# Como le aplico formato a una formula para que devuelva solo dos decimales?

Tags: php, javascript

Hola amigos tengo estas dos formulas:

```
function agregar() {
  subtotal[cont]=number_format((articulo*precio),2);   
  total=total+subtotal[cont];
}
```

Ejemplo:

```
subtotal[cont]=67,88*67,88= 4608.88916544
```

Si el usuario ingresa en los respectivos campos cifras con decimales devuelve valores con muchos decimales, ¿cómo hago para ponerle formato y que solo muestre dos decimales?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer por medio de [number_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php):

```
echo number_format($tuvariable, 2, '.', '');
```

Esto te va a regresar el número que le pases como parámetro con dos decimales o los que tú le establezcas, remplazando el 2.

Por ejemplo:

```
$tuvariable = 7.02311332;
echo number_format($tuvariable, 2, '.', '');
// Esto imprime 7.02
echo number_format($tuvariable, 0, '.', '');
// Esto imprime 7
```

Basándonos en tus comentarios que mencionas después que estás utilizando Javascript lo puedes hacer con:

```
total.toFixed(2);
```

Convierte un número en una cadena, redondeando el número para mantener solo dos decimales.

Comment: debo meter el formato dentro de la formula ya que depues tomo esos datos y voy alimentando el detalle de la factura, yo intente meterlo alli en la formula pero no pude

Comment: Es una función nativa de php debe funcionarte, simplemente abajo de todos los pasos pon $total = number_format($total, 2, '.', '');, o simplemente mete total+subtotal[count]; en el primer parametro del number format.

Comment: lo hice pero no funcionó seguire intentando de todas formas te doy gracias por la ayuda, esa funcion ya le he usado pero como estoy dentro de un scrip no se como meterlo, en mi caso no tengo $variables, son variables sin el simbolo

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta y mostrar el fragmento completo de como lo has intentado y asi te puedo ayudar.

Comment: La edite con un intento

Comment: ¿Cómo estás utilizando PHP sin hacer uso de $, estás utilizando Constantes?

Comment: estoy utilizando Javascrip

Comment: En la publicación pusiste PHP y en la etiqueta PHP, por eso te di esa respuesta, ya edite mi respuesta para agregar lo de Javascript.